# What is the performance benefit when using a temporary table to update a regular table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to understand what the performance benefit between two different methods of updating multiple table rows.

For the first method we have an explicit update statement for each line to be altered.

i.e.

```
 update my_table set my_field='A' where id=1;
 update my_table set my_field='B' where id=2;
 update my_table set my_field='C' where id=3;
 update my_table set my_field='D' where id=4;
 update my_table set my_field='E' where id=5;
```

For the second method we use a temporary table.

i.e.

```
 create temporary table my_temp_table (id,val);

 insert into my_temp_table value (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E');

 update my_table t, my_temp_table tt set t.val=tt.val where t.id=tt.id;
```

I've been told that the second method is more efficient and thus superior.  I just don't understand why this is so.

Sure we have 5 queries vs 3 queries but that last query is essentially still doing all those updates, albeit implicitly?  Plus it adds in a join too.

So I'm just curious as to why using a temporary table is better?  Is it simply 3 is less than 5, and as such, is better?

EDIT: We are using InnoDB and not explicitly using transactions.  This is just a one off batch update pushed into MYSQL via a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's look at a different aspect.  Is your table ENGINE=InnoDB?  If so, and you have not done anything (yet) about "transactions"?  Then 5 Updates is 5 transactions.  There is a significant overhead for each transactions.  Hence, this would be a lot better:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...;
UPDATE ...;
...
COMMIT;
```

You had 5 statements versus 3.  I turned the 5 into 7.

If, instead, there were 500 updates to do, that would be 502 versus 3.  Now the overhead of extra round-trips to the server becomes significant.  At this point (502 statements versus 3), creating the tmp table, etc, becomes significantly better.

(There is no need for `BEGIN...COMMIT` on the tmp approach; the UPDATE is a 'transaction' unto itself, assuming autocommit=1.)

Comment: Regarding (there is no need for begin...commit in the tmp approach because the UPDATE is one statement, so a transaction by itself):  Also because the tmp table is hidden from other sessions, there is no need to put the insert into the tmp table and the update in one transaction.

Comment: So at scale it makes a huge difference due to the overheads involved.   I guess that makes sense.